# Count total number of pages globally

Tags: confluence

We are preparing for an upgrade of confluence.  We are documenting all the current information about our confluence instance before we do the upgrade.

I need to know how many **Total** pages there are globally within confluence.

From the administrators console I can see this information

```
Content (All Versions)         91892
Content (Current Versions)     18194
```

It is my understanding that this information is total content, including blog posts, attachments, comments etc... Not specifically Page Count

I have found some macros that will tell me how many pages exist in a particular space, but that does not quite do what I need as we have over 200 spaces currently.

The database we have this on is: Microsoft SQL Server.

Confluence Version: 3.4.2

Is there any way to get the total number of pages within confluence globally?

Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Yes, the system information page lists the total count of ALL content elements.

If you want to know the figures by content type you could query the database with the following SQL:

**ALL**

```
SELECT contenttype, count(*) FROM content c GROUP BY c.contenttype
```

**Current Versions**

```
SELECT contenttype, count(*) FROM content c WHERE c.prevver is null GROUP BY c.contenttype
```